# Merging complex types

Tags: terraform

I'm struggling with merging maps that have duplicate keys, since the built-in `merge` function will only keep the latest argument that has matching keys or attributes.

My maps are of the following shape:

```
{mykey = ["item1","item2","item3"]}
{mykey = ["item4","item5","item6"]}
```

The merge function simply returns `{mykey = ["item4","item5","item6"]}` (or whatever is the last argument). I'd like to compose a map like

```
{mykey = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"]}
```

I don't believe there's a function I can use to achieve this. However, I suspect that a for loop is the right approach, yet my knowledge is failing me.

---

Hi @MattSchuchard, thanks for your help. The parent map structure (if I am following you correctly), is a local variable. I am using keys and values from this local in order to retrieve `object_ids` from the `azuread_users` and `azuread_groups` data sources. My locals looks like this:

```
locals {
  roles = {
    role1 = {
      users = ["user1@domain.com","user2@domain.com"]
      groups = ["myGroup1","myGroup2"]
  }
}
```

I am referencing this local in the data sources as follows:

```
data azuread_users.lookup {
  for_each = local.roles
  user_principal_names = each.values.users
}

data azuread_groups.lookup {
  for_each = local.roles
  display_names = each.values.groups
}
```

These data sources export `object_ids` as an attribute (which I will then use when adding members to groups in a resource block). The exported attributes are in the shape detailed in my original post.

I would like to compose a combined list of all `object_ids` exported from both `data.azuread_users.lookup` and `data.azuread_groups.lookup` which I can then provide as an argument when creating a group:

```
resource "azuread_group" "my_group" {
  members = $myCombinedListOfObjectIDs
}
```

Comment: We need to see the full parent map structure. Non-parent keys may be omitted.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, I edited my original post due to comment length restrictions,

Comment: If `object_ids` is a list, I think you can merge two lists and provide it as a value to `members` argument if that is also a list or a set (I think).

Comment: That was the extra information we needed to see, but now I am a bit confused. At first you were asking about combining the values of multiple nested keys with the same name, and now the question is about combining lists exported as attributes from data? Is there some reason you cannot `concat` each of the `object_ids`?

Comment: I understand the confusion. In my limited understanding, are they not the same thing? The attributes exported from the data blocks will be a map of keys (from each.key) and values (a list of object_ids), as is the map of keys and values initially provided as an example. I want to plan for the existence of many roles in my locals, and each one will produce a separate map. Am I missing something very fundamental?

Comment: Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details. So your maps have only **one** key called `mykey` and you only want to join those two maps, exactly you showed in the question?

Comment: Exactly @Marcin, my keys are not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you want a list/map you can use this:

```
locals {
  input  = { mykey = ["item1", "item2", "item3"] }
  input2 = { mykey = ["item4", "item5", "item6"] }
  merged = concat(local.input.mykey, local.input2.mykey)
  merged_mykey = {
    mykeys = concat(local.input.mykey, local.input2.mykey)
  }
}
```

The output is

```
> local.merged_mykey
{
  "mykeys" = [
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
    "item5",
    "item6",
  ]
}

> local.merged
[
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3",
  "item4",
  "item5",
  "item6",
]
```

If you're worried about duplicates you can wrap it in a distinct call. https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/distinct